# Segurança em um sistema web, verificando outros conteúdos abertos

Tags: aplicação-web, segurança

Já vi alguns sites que possuem provas *online* com monitoramento, captando quais telas o usuário abriu no computador, seja aba de navegadores ou outros softwares, essa pergunta pode ser fechada por ser na opinião de alguns 'ampla', mas ao meu ponto de vista não é, se trata apenas de um *start* para esse caminho, onde já vi muitos desenvolvedores terem curiosidade em aprender.

A minha maior dúvida é como pesquisar conteúdo referente ao assunto, existem termos específicos? Se algum membro da comunidade estiver disposto a dar uma resposta mais ampla, dizendo ferramentas que podem ser usadas para isso eu e outras pessoas ficaríamos gratos.

PS: Lembrando que se trata de um `website`. Qual o caminho para realizar esse tipo de verificação? Resumindo, capturar abas ou softwares abertos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara o que vc está procurando se chama Telemetria

E existe várias técnicas e formas de se capturar esse tipo de informação, alguns sites utilizam plugins para esse monitoramento outros fazem a implementação no próprio site

Te aconselho a procurar artigo acadêmicos (de preferência em inglês) pq ai tu vai oq é de mais novo referente ao assunto

Comment: Obrigado, vou dar uma pesquisada sobre o mesmo